# HTML/javascript Automatic popup instead of onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I got this input right now and it works as it should. But I want to create another page with the same popup, but this one should run automaticly instead of onclick. Any tips on how to get it working?

```
<input type="submit" id="checkin" method="post" action="checkin.php" href = "javascript:void(1)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'" value="Check in">
    <div id="light1" class="white_content">
        <form id="formen" name="myForm" action="checkin.php" method="POST">'
        sAlot of content
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) write the logic for displaing the popup in script and remove the input tag

```
  <div id="light1" class="white_content">
        <form id="formen" name="myForm" action="checkin.php" method="POST">'
        sAlot of content
        </form>
  </div>


<script>
    document.getElementById('light1').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'
</script>
```

2) Or you can also trigger the click event on input  using jquery

```
<input type="submit" id="checkin" method="post" action="checkin.php" href = "javascript:void(1)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'" value="Check in">
    <div id="light1" class="white_content">
        <form id="formen" name="myForm" action="checkin.php" method="POST">'
        sAlot of content
        </form>
    </div>


 <script> 
      $('#checkin').trigger('click');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the "click" on the page load: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

e.g. :

```
$('#checkin').trigger('click');
```

Although I can't remember whether or not you will need to put your "onclick" code into a:

```
$('#checkin').on( 'click', function() {
```

(I would do it anyway because IMO it's cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the JS in a script tag before your closing body tag instead of it being an onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Add your script to `onload` handler of `body` tag the same way as to `onclick`.

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('light1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
  <!-- all your stuff -->

</body>
```